# Is there any way to disallow the '$' character in a Salesforce password?

Tags: ant, passwords

Is there any way to prevent certain characters from being used in Salesforce passwords?

Specifically, the '$' character causes problems when using ANT for continuous integration, as this symbol represents a variable in ANT, so if '$' appears in a password, ANT tries to break up the password.

E.g. A password property as follows causes problems in ANT:

*sf.deploy.password=TE$TPASSWORD*

ANT will split the password and just use 'TE', resulting in a login error.

I've had a look at [password policies](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_password_policies_ref.htm&language=en_US) for Salesforce but there don't seem to be any options for restricting the symbols available for use in passwords.

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, it would be in the password policies if it were an option. So you seem to be out of luck. :(

Comment: Yes, those were my thoughts as well. I'm not even sure if you could create anything custom to tackle this - the only way I could see it would be to put a trigger on User that checks the content of a password. However I doubt that you can access password content from Apex somehow...

Comment: Nope, definitely not. No way a company like Salesforce would even store the plaintext. Gotta chalk this one up to user training. Surely there can't be that many people using ANT on your team?

Comment: I'm curious, does ANT store passwords in plain text? Something doesn't sit right with me that something like: `sf.deploy.password=TE$TPASSWORD` isn't encrypted. I'd personally argue this is more of an issue with ANT itself rather than Salesforce.

Comment: Isn't it easier to just try and escape the '$' character in ant?

Comment: At the moment we're using Cloudbees/Jenkins to run the build jobs, it's a pretty basic setup right now. There's some info here about encrypting ANT build scripts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452216/encrypt-ant-build-file). Escaping in Cloudbees is fine, just means a little bit more manual configuration for our build jobs. Just wondering if there was any way to kill the problem so that we could keep the build jobs standardised if that makes sense?

Comment: @AdrianLarson yeah it's not a huge problem, just affects a couple of logins at the moment. More curiosity than anything else! Thanks